# Publishing MSTest results to team members

Tags: tfs, mstest

I am trying to publish MSTest results to the team. I'd like to send all the test results by email, or have a testresults.trx file attached, or something similar.

How can this be done in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using [trx2html](http://trx2html.codeplex.com/) tool to convert MSTest report files to readable form (html files). These html files are attached to email send by MSbuild script to all contacts specified in the mailing list.

In the TFS you have to update build template. Call trx2html tool using InvokeProcess activity after every MStest call and at the end pick all html files and send e-mail using Send email activity, but I don't think there is such activity. You have to implement it or send mail using some external tool/script.

Comment: Can I use this trx2html in workflow activity? As I am using tfs 2010.

Comment: Yes you can, using InvokeProcess activity

Comment: I am sorry, I should read your answer carefully :). You already mentioned about processinvoke activity.